# How to query a nested <Boolean> and <List> tags inside a <value> node in a SQL Server XML column?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Given the following XML in a VARCHAR column:

```
<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="IIQDisabled">
            <value>
                <Boolean>true</Boolean>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="IIQLocked">
            <value>
                <Boolean/>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="accountFlags">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>Normal User Account</String>
                    <String>User Account is Disabled</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="company" value="Acme"/>
        <entry key="department" value="Service"/>
        <entry key="name" value="Joe.Blow"/>
        <entry key="objectClass">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>top</String>
                    <String>person</String>
                    <String>organizationalPerson</String>
                    <String>user</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="userPrincipalName" value="joeblow@acme.com"/>
    </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I am able to successfully extract [userPrincipalName], but I cannot figure out the necessary syntax for [IIQDisabled] and [accountFlags] (which has multiple items,  ideally I'd like to concatenate them together, but my primary concern is [IIQDisabled]).

The SQL I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
TOP 100
  link.id
, linkMap.value('(./entry[@key="userPrincipalName"]/@value)[1]',    'varchar(500)')  as userPrincipalName
, linkMap.value('(./entry[@key="IIQDisabled"]/@value)[1]',          'varchar(500)')  as IIQDisabled
, linkMap.value('(./entry[@key="IIQDisabled"]/@value)[1]',          'bit')           as IIQDisabled_as_bit
FROM 
[identityiq].[spt_link]         link    
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CAST(link.attributes AS varchar(MAX)) AS XML))         linkAttributes(AttributesAsXml)
    CROSS APPLY linkAttributes.AttributesAsXml.nodes('/Attributes/Map')         linkAttributesMap(linkMap)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

`@value` revers to an XML attribute named "value". This is correct for the userPrincipalName XML element, but for IIQDisabled, the value you want is content nested two deep within the `entry` XML element inside `value` and `Boolean`.  Try:

```
linkMap.value('(./entry[@key="IIQDisabled"]/value/Boolean/text())[1]', 'bit') as IIQDisabled_as_bit
```

(Addendum) As for retrieving account flags, you can try something like the following to retrieve a comma separated list:

```
, (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(s.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'), ', ')
    FROM linkAttributesMap.linkMap.nodes('./entry[@key="accountFlags"]/value/List/String') AS S(s)
  ) AS accountFlags -- SQL Server 2017 (14) or later
, STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + s.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    FROM linkAttributesMap.linkMap.nodes('./entry[@key="accountFlags"]/value/List/String') AS S(s)
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 2, '') AS accountFlags -- older releases
```

I do not have SQL Server 2017, so that piece is not tested. For older releases, the `FOR XML PATH('')` hack is a technique for concatenating strings. The `STUFF()` is used to eliminate the initial leading comma/space.

Comment: @Charlieface - Thanks. I've edited the answer above to add `/text()`.